# Display posted values back in laravel using 'old' not 'Form'

Tags: php, laravel

I know how to display normal variables values back using old('zipCode') syntax.

But how to display array, i tried few websites searching they have used Form:: but i am not using it.

Below is my blade.php code

```
 <div class="set">
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <input name="contacts[0][firstName]" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <input name="contacts[0][lastName]" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <input name="contacts[0][role]" type="text" />
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

PHP Code

```
    $validator = Validator::make($request->all(),
    [
        'contact.*.firstName' => 'required',
        'contact.*.email' => 'required|email'
    ]);

    if ($validator->fails())
    {
        $this->throwValidationException(
            $request, $validator
        );
    }
```

So how can i use old and display back the old values, basicaly in a loop

Thanks in advance...

**Solved Code**

```
@if(old('contacts')==null)

    <div class="set">

        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-4"><input name="contacts[0][firstName]" type="text" value="Sharath"
                                         placeholder="First Name"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><input name="contacts[0][lastName]" type="text" value="M"
                                         placeholder="Last Name"/></div>
            <div class="col-md-4"><input name="contacts[0][role]" type="text"
                                         placeholder="Designation"/></div>
        </div>
    </div>

@else

    @foreach(old('contacts') as $no => $contact)

        <div class="set">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-4"><input name="contacts[{{$no}}][firstName]" type="text" value="{{$contact['firstName']}}"
                                             placeholder="First Name"/></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><input name="contacts[{{$no}}][lastName]" type="text" value="{{$contact['lastName']}}"
                                             placeholder="Last Name"/></div>
                <div class="col-md-4"><input name="contacts[{{$no}}][role]" type="text" value="{{$contact['role']}}"
                                             placeholder="Designation"/></div>
            </div>
        </div>

    @endforeach

@endif
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<div class="set">
  @foreach($contacts as $conact)
     <div class="row">
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <input name="{{ $contact[firstName] }}" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <input name="{{ $contact[lastName] }}" type="text" />
          </div>
          <div class="col-md-4">
              <input name="{{ $contact[role] }}" type="text" />
          </div>
    </div>
  @endforeach
</div>
```

Use **your variable** name instead of **$contacts** and Try it

Comment: initially **$contacts** is not set so it crashes. Anyways i checked for isset so it solves. But next time when the input is posted back, the above code still doesn't work.